# JSTL list without foreach

Tags: list, jstl

I have two lists.
One of them ("a") is list of different object, include lists.
The second one ("b") include one object for any object at "a".
For example, 
if "a" has 6 items, and one of them is list of 4 elements - "b" has 9 items.

I want to fill "b" according to "a" list.
In java this can be done so:

```
for(int i = 0, j=0; i<a.size(); i++){
  if(a.at(i).size()>1)
      for(int k=0; k<a.at(i).size(); k++)
          b.at(j++) = a(i).at(k);
  else b.at(j++) = a(i);
}
```

How can I do like that at jstl?
I know how to use foreach on simple list, but how can I use index like j, which Promoted manually (j++)?

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will help anyone...

Here the answer:

```
<c:set var="i" value="0" />
<c:forEach items="${a}" var="item" varStatus="dep">
    <c:when test="${item.size > 1}">
       <form:input path="b[${i}].value" value="true"/> 
       <c:set var="i" value="${i+1}" />
...
```